# Using dottie js to access elements in an array (using index)

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm using dottie to access values from an object safely. Something like this works

```
var dottie = require("dottie")
var x = { names: [{name: 'hello'},{name: 'world'}] }
dottie.get(x, 'names')
```

However, i see issues trying something like:

```
var dottie = require("dottie")
var x = { names: [{name: 'hello'},{name: 'world'}] }
dottie.get(x, 'names[0]')
```

and

```
var dottie = require("dottie")
var x = { names: [{name: 'hello'},{name: 'world'}] }
dottie.get(x, 'names[names.length-1]')
```

Are there any libraries that will allow me to do the following safely? Basically eval expressions against an object?

Answer (score 0):

Lodash `_.get()` can help you with the cases 1 & 2, while 3 would required `_.last()` as well.

**Note:** importing the entire lodash library for this use cases would be an overkill in the web browser, so you should use tree shaking and the webpack and babel lodash plugins to reduce size, or import just the [`lodash/get`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get) and  [`lodash/last`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.last) packages.

```js
var x = { names: [{name: 'hello'},{name: 'world'}] }
console.log(_.get(x, 'names'))

var x = { names: [{name: 'hello'},{name: 'world'}] }
console.log(_.get(x, 'names[0]'))

var x = { names: [{name: 'hello'},{name: 'world'}] }
console.log(_.last(_.get(x, 'names')))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```